Apple ID is disabled permanently
My Apple ID has been disabled permanently and I cannot download or update any of my apps and I would like to know if there’s another solution or way I can download and update my apps? Because I tried changing my Apple ID and it’s still saying it’s disabled permanently.

Contact Apple Support. There’s not much we can do to help you.

Are you able to sign into your account at https://appleid.apple.com/ ?

If your Apple ID is permanently disabled, you will not have access to downloads or updates. Even creating a new Apple ID and signing in may not solve the issue, as the disabled Apple ID could still be linked to your device. The most effective solution is to reach out to Apple Support for assistance. They can offer personalized advice and potentially help reactivate your Apple ID or suggest a different way to manage your apps.
